# swift - Translate a UIImageView on fix screen coordinate wth animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation, translate-animation

I have a UIImageView object which is in center of the screen on full screen . I have made a animation that perform scale and translation at the same code. Here is the source code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        let originalTransform = self.idImageView.transform
        let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.idImageView.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        self.animationCompeletedSuccessfully(finished)
    })
```

I want my UIImageView move to co-ordinate of x=100 and y=100 but that translate move it 100 point relative to it's center. How can i translate it on window co-ordinate systems??
[Apple Documentation of traslatedBy(x: , y:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455822-translatedby)
I have read this one but couldn't understand clearly about co-ordiante systems

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your `imageview` center has `x`, `y` coordinates and `width`, `height`.
Your desired destination: `destinationX`, `destinationY`

Your translation would be:

- by x: `destinationX - x + width/2`
- by y: `destinationY - y + height/2`

Remember if you do the scale, your `width` and `height` should be multiplied by scaleRatio

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's partially working. I don't know why. It is moving my view near the expected point. And i don't understant your last line. can you explain please?

Comment: In your case it would be `destinationX - x + width/2 * 0.2` and same to `y`

Comment: Please, edit your code how you implemented it and then i can help you